# Good programming practices: referencing arrays

Tags: php, coding-style

This question specifically relates to my experience with PHP, but there's no reason why it shouldn't apply to other languages.

Having set `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);` during testing, I noticed that I had some notices, such as `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ChrisW/public_html/admin.php on line 122`.  This comes about as I store warnings about a form (unfilled values, invalid values, etc) in an array, and then access them:

```
echo $errorsArray[0] . '<label for="name" id="name-label">Your Name</label>
<input id="name" name="name" value="' . $name . '" />';
```

with my errors array being `$errorsArray = array($nameError, $emailError);` in my validation function.  The 1st time the page is loaded, I show the form:

```
if(count($_POST) == 0)
{
  $name="";
  $email="";
  $errorsArray = array();
  form_display($name, $number, $errorsArray); 
}
```

In an ideal world:

- does it matter about the notices?
- should I initialise the array by doing `$errorsArray("","");`, or
- Should I check if the array is empty when I reference it (such as by changing `echo $errorsArray[0]` to `echo (count($errorsArray[0])==0 ? "" : $errorsArray[0])`?

Hopefully, there'll be a fairly black and white answer - I don't want to cause a long discussion!

Comment: Style is very rarely black, or white.  The exception is when it's mentioned in an official style-guide... but even then it will be contested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Production code SHOULD NOT raise notices. This causes scroll blindness - you get used to having a lot of meaningless messages, so you don't notice the important one (until it's too late).

Random comments:

- it's not really important how you avoid notices, in your case it might be initializing $errorsArray to an empty array;
- holding errors in an array like that is probably not the best idea anyway. Now you have two styles of passing data to your view: one by global variables ($name, $password), one by values indexed by numbers ($errorsArray[0], $errorsArray[1]). The first one is better, the second one is OK, and you could think of some better ones ($data['name']['errors']). But the general rule is: stick to one way of doing things. As an old Polish saying goes: "może być chujowo, byle jednakowo" (roughly translated: might not be the best way, but at least it's uniform).

Comment: Thanks - the scroll blindness is a good point, and a good reason to get rid of all warnings / notices.  Your 2nd bullet point is useful - I'm not a programmer by trade (as you may have guessed!) - I'm a chemist who's taught myself programming over the past few years...

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by FakeRainBrigand, there won't be an absolute answer. Personally I'd say that notices are there for a reason, and to avoid being flooded by too many irrelevant error messages, one should probably get rid them even if it makes the code longer, and seemingly more verbose.

PHP can be a bit error-prone due to its inconsistencies and all the spots where something is done implicitly or where potential errors are ignored by default (such as in this case). Therefore it might be wise to do stuff explicitly, leaving no doubt about the intention.